# swf file is not accessible because of .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website which is working MVC mode and now I'm trying to use a swf file with JavaScript for supercookies, but server doesn't serve the swf file. In my opinion that's because of `.htaccess` file.
I've changed it to:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php [NC,QSA]

AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf
```

But the swf file is still not accessible. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an exception to the rewrite conditions to allow direct access to the .swf files and possibly the folder the swf file is in

I have used the following on simple MVC sites to allow direct access to files or folders that i do not want to be handled by the MVC engine :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(controller\.php|script\.php|images|css|js|forum|pdfs|xmls|pdf|robots|.*.swf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller.php/$1 [L]
```

I think for you the last rewrite rule should have a condition something like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(.*.swf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php [NC,QSA]
```

you may want to read up on the mod_rewrite documentation.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
or look at some tutorials on mod_rewrite
http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/